# Combo Box Programming

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am very new to VBA coding and I am having an issue with the comboboxes.
Here is the code I have.
Everything else is working except for the comboboxes.
I receive this error when it gets to the row containing

```
cells(emptyrow,4).value=combobox1.value
```

Run-Time error '1004': "Application-defined or object-defined error"

```
Private Sub commandbutton1_Click()
Sheet2.Activate
emptyrow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("a:a")) + 1
Cells(emptyrow, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
Cells(emptyrow, 2).Value = "1"
End If
If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
Cells(emptyrow, 2).Value = "2"
End If
If CheckBox3.Value = True Then
Cells(emptyrow, 2).Value = "3"
End If
Cells(emptyrow, 3).Value = TextBox2.Value
Cells(emptryrow, 4).Value = ComboBox1.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 5).Value = ComboBox2.Value
Cells(emptyrow, 6).Value = TextBox3.Value
If CheckBox4.Value = True Then
Cells(emptyrow, 7).Value = "Tool Break"
End If
If CheckBox5.Value = True Then
Cells(emptyrow, 7).Value = "Tool Wear"
End If
If CheckBox4.Value = True Then
Cells(emptyrow, 8).Value = ComboBox3.Value
End If
If CheckBox5.Value = True Then
Cells(emptyrow, 8).Value = ComboBox4.Value
End If
```

Comment: What does the "issue" mean? Is the cell where the combo value should be dropped empty? Does your code raise an error on a specific row? What wrong does it happen running the code?

Comment: It raises and error when it gets to the row containing ``` cells(emptyrow,4).value = combobox1.value```

Comment: Run-Time error '1004': "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Missing `Option Explicit` at the top of the module, which would flag `emptryrow` as being an undeclared variable due to the typo. Always declare your variables: `Dim emptyrow As Long`.

Comment: Well I feel like an idiot lol. Thank you. That fixed it.